# can we query SOSL using REST API?

Tags: rest, sosl

can we query SOSL using REST API? As we can do with SOQL like this :
/services/data/v37.0/query/?q=

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do SOSL query using REST Api.

The api would be - `/services/data/v37.0/search/?q=SOSL search string`

The SOSL search string needs to be URL encoded.

Here is a link for more details - [SOSL Search using REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search.htm)

Here is an way how you can make a successful REST API call.

```
String salesforceHost = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();

String url =  salesforceHost + '/services/data/v37.0/search/?q='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode('FIND {Joe Smith} IN Name Fields RETURNING lead', 'UTF-8'); // use your own SOSL statement

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());

Http http = new Http();

HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('res'+res.getbody());
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52975/discussion-between-oookkk-and-santanu-halder).

Comment: I did'nt find any solution of this issue.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all..
BUt I found solution for that also
/services/data/v37.0/ParametrisedSearch/?q= isTest

Comment: Can you add details on this. Just one liner won't help others having same issue.